# How to execute a query in couchbase server

Tags: couchbase, bucket

I want to execute this query : **select path_id , usr_id from `pth`**, so I can get all data from my bucket "path" so I can use it to generate data for my bucket "step".

I tried to create a index using this query :

**CREATE INDEX `idx_xref` ON `pth`(`path_id`,`usr_id`);**

And then I executed this query : 
**select path_id , usr_id from `pth`**

I'm expecting a json results .. but I always get this error :

**[
  {
    "code": 4000,
    "msg": "No index available on keyspace pth that matches your query. Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online.",
    "query_from_user": "select path_id , usr_id from `pth`;"
  }
]**

Comment: Can you check the output of query "select * from system:indexes;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**select path_id, usr_id from pth where path_id IS NOT MISSING**

The leading key of the index needs to be present in the WHERE clause for index selection.

You can find more details here:
https://blog.couchbase.com/n1ql-practical-guide-second-edition/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a primary index : 
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON pth
Thank you all for your help :))